# "How to... ?" questions

Tags: discussion, questions, languages

Is it just me that gets slightly annoyed when reading a question beginning with "How to", implying the poster is providing an explanation/tutorial rather than asking a question? Is this simply creeping into the English language and why is it so common?

Related: [Is a question beginning with "How to" grammatically correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/101345/is-a-question-beginning-with-how-to-grammatically-correct)

For the sake of discussion: Should Stack Overflow include a hint to guide against choosing such a title?

Comment: Feel free to edit to a better title. Try to make edits as complete as possible fixing the majority of problems with a post

Comment: P.s. almost all of the questions asked here are technically off topic. We are woefully unqualified to answer questions on trajectories of languages

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about trends in the usage of the English language rather than discussing, requesting or asking a question about a feature or part of Stack Overflow or the Stack Exchange network of sites

Comment: I ask here as it's mainly about S.O. I could go on to say, "should SO include a grammatical check in the title?", but I'd definitely be against it.

Comment: I'd be suprised if it wasn't a more general pattern of speech

Comment: Don't downvote because you don't like the idea, the guy only opened it for a discussion... this reminds me a video tutorial (and even a good one) about how to perform some operations in win8. this video got so many dislikes just for the fact it's about it's about win8.

Comment: @Yosi that's how voting works on Meta. Upvote if you like it, downvote if you don't.

Comment: @Stijn Meh, for a discussion question that's debatable though. I'd say that if you have an argument against the premise of the discussion, then make it an answer.

Comment: @Bart At least that's my understanding of it. I could be wrong, I still consider myself a Meta newbie :) I've removed my downvote.

Comment: @Stijn Ideally the "no" or "don't like this" downvotes should be reserved for feature requests. And there is kinda-sorta a feature request in there. But hey, we're guessing at vote reasons now anyway. Not much of a point to that.

Comment: @Yosi Most of the downvotes were before the final paragraph was added. At which point the question was off topic

Comment: @RichardTingle - That's true, I just saw the previous revisions.

Answer (score 8):

This is why we have community editing.

If you feel that a question contains poor grammar (as in this case), misspellings or is otherwise unclear feel free to make a suggested edit. However try to make edits as complete as possible fixing the majority of problems with a post.

Comment: it doesn't really make any difference to the question, it's just petty pedantry on my part. The shear number of these questions makes editing impractical. I'm just interested in why it's so common.

Comment: @jozxyqk Ah, the "why" is hugely out of our area. I have no idea if it would be on topic at "English Language and Usage" but it's the only place it has a hope of being on topic

Answer (score 4):

Basically, you are right (grammar wise).

**BUT** - There are tons of features with much higher priority, and there are many other "bad habits" that bothers the community like - missing information, posting duplicates, etc.

If this bothers you in person, feel free to comment/suggest an edit. If users will embrace that, it really shows you have a point.

Anyway, I don't think that something should be done about it.

Answer (score 2):

> Should stack overflow include a hint to guide against choosing such a title?

No. There are lots of titles that could be phrased better. Before you know it, you'd have a huge list of hints that people will just ignore.

If you take it even further and disallow submitting such a title, people will just remove the "How to" part and be done with it.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not just you that is annoyed by bad grammar.  However, this site will never correct the habits of the world's speakers.  Just go with whatever, innit?

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, SO **does** provide an excellent set of hints and tips on how to answer. Many people just don't read them. And many don't have English as their first language, so really - if it annoys you, fix it. Otherwise ignore it.